Unwanted Instructions Showing Up on xdbg
I'm using x64dbg and am writing some instructions in a region of the executable that I 'hollowed out' previously (just set to NOPs). After entering a simple xor instruction, shown below, some random instruction pops up in the line below:
xor rbx,rbx
or dl,byte ptr ds:[rax-6F6F6F70]

The line below is totally random to me and I don't know why its showing up.
Note that multiple instructions randomly show up when I enter other instructions as well. There doesn't seem to be a correlation for which commands in particular trigger this to happen.
Can anybody explain the cause for this? Thanks.

What byte sequences are you using for NOPs?  If they're not 1-byte 0x90 NOPs (and you don't take care to pad with NOPs until the next NOP boundary), then overwriting part of a long NOP with a shorter instruction will mean decode starts with some byte that wasn't previously an opcode.  It might eventually get back into sync with your NOPs, or get stuck into some other pattern.  P.S. xor ebx, ebx will do the same thing as xor rbx, rbx in 1 fewer byte.

Related: Why does x/i on gdb give different results then disassemble? / How does an instruction decoder tell the difference between a prefix and a primary opcode? / What happens if `objdump -d --start-address` starts printing from the middle of an x86 instruction?

That last one is probably a duplicate for the symptoms.  If you have a goal that includes having execution fall off the end of your new instructions into the NOPs, that would be a different question so you can ask that if you want an answer to it.  e.g. use 8-byte NOPs aligned by 8, so you can insert some instructions and end with a NOP that gets you to an 8-byte boundary, the start of an existing long-NOP.

That instruction encodes as 0a 90 90 90 90 90, the 90's were nops before this incident and 0a is also known as the newline character, is there any chance that the enter key was involved?
